# Need to implement Power Bi report to angular App with login

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, powerbi

Have a Good Day

I need some help regarding Power Bi,

**Requirement:** I need to Implement the Power BI report in Angular Application With Login security. anyone have idea How can I achieve this and have any blog so Please share the link with me. it would be helpful for me

**I have got permission and allowed all-access, i'm able to get an access token using rest API in Postman but getting stuck while integrating rest API in Angular 6+**

const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };

```
const body = new HttpParams()
  .set('client_id', 'xxxxxx')
  .set('client_secret', 'xxxxxx')
  .set('grant_type', 'password')
  .set('scope', 'openid')
  .set('resource', 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api')
  .set('username', 'xxxxxx')
  .set('password', 'xxxxxx');


this.http.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", body.toString(), httpOptions)
  .subscribe(
    (res) => {
      console.log("access Token.........", res);
    },
    err => console.log(err)
  );
```